# Unable to insert UIScrollView above UIView to another scene using XCode 8

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode8.2

I have an existing iPad app (Portrait mode) where I am trying to add Landscape mode in XCode.  I have been able to do it on the first simple view, seen below by changing the class in XCode to UIScrollView and the UIView fell into line below it (I believe the UIView was added by XCode, but not sure tho').  The scrollview works perfectly when in landscape mode.

When I try to do the same thing to the next scene, it won't allow me to change the order again, as seen in the following image; I'm not sure why it won't allow the same thing:

Any ideas?  Is there another way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**
Here is the image showing the position of attempting to insert a UIScrollView in the UIVIewController (Book Details is the UIViewController; Book Detail View is the UIView):

[image]

Comment: Try to add navigation above scroll view.

Comment: In your existing project, you have embed the scrollview and then a view and have to do what I said in answer. This is the only solution. If you have new then pls aware me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers solved the issue of altering an *existing* app, so I requested Apple Technical Support.  They didn't solve it either, but rather gave me some docs to look at.  @Aragunz probably came the closest by suggesting it was/is a problem within XCode 8.  My only option left is to rewrite the storyboard from scratch, saving the existing classes.

Answer (score 3):

Well do this on second controller:
 1. Delete the main `UIView` from `UIViewController` scene then,
 2. Add a `UIScrollView` on top of it.
 3. Add the `UIView` as `UIScrollView` subview.

You will have the perfect order and the desired result like in the first scene.
In your case select the View under Bottom layout Guide, press backspace, drag and drop a UIScrollView on that Book Details. Cheers.

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Unable to add UIViewController; in your instructions, were you suggesting a brand new "scene", where I add a UIViewController and the UIScrollView under the _new_ UIViewController or _over_ it?  Then _moving_ the existing UIView and related objects to the _new_ scene?  Then deleting the _old_ scene...

Comment: Not necessarly delete entire scene, just click on the UIView press backspace it removes the UIView then get a UIScrollView and drag and drop on that UIViewController you having problem with. Hope it helps, let me know if u need more explanation.

Comment: When I _backspace_ the UIView, it deletes it _ and all of the objects underneath it_, which clearly won't work... I can not get the UIScrollView above the UIViewController no matter how many different ways I try... (see image in original question)

Comment: Bro, if u actually want to acomplish the desired result this is the way, if u want to switch from one to another its fine, u can get that view and save to another scene before u add UIScroll View, let me add an image to show if u want the controller that way.

Comment: OK... finally got it positioned by cutting the UIView, adding the UIScrollView, then pasting the UIView under the UIScrollView.  However, no data appears in the UIView's objects (all object connections are still there in UIView).  Am I missing some connections between the UIView and the UIScrollView?  (I'm going to do some reading and see what I can find, but thought you might know right off).

Comment: And it still doesn't scroll... I matched the size and origin of the scroll view with that of the UIView... no change! I think I'll contact Apple and request Developer Support.. thanks for your time... SD

Comment: @SpokaneDude Do you have bothViewControllers, can u plz send me in an archive i will help u out.

Comment: Not entire app, just those two controllers, and scenes from that, copy and paste them on a new project's storyboard and both controllers. Not entire project. I am all in for helping you.

Comment: here you go... let me know if you need anything else... thank you, I appreciate your dedication and support...

https://ufile.io/50886

Comment: I wish i could help you more about this, but those controller scene dont help much unfortunatelly, and as i can see it maybe be constrain related or approach related not a difference a scroll view vs uiview.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of because nothing worked... thanks again, I'm going to give you the credit for the answer and the bounty, unless someone else has a better, working answer.

Comment: Thank you, i really wish i could help, if u think of any way i can help plz let me know.

Answer (score 1):

### HOW TO DEAL WITH SCROLLVIEW

1. Your `navigation bar` is always be at the top with height `44px` and top space of `20px` ( top `20px` is for the status bar i.e. charging, network etc icon you see in your device ).

**Reason** behind to fix the `navigation bar` at top is that wherever user is in the VC you always have to show him in which VC he is present at that time otherwise your app quality may be get low(i said may be). After all you can add `navigation Bar` in `UIScrollView` its your choice.

Top green view you are seeing, I just taking a view as a `statusBar` of height `20px` to show the difference.

[image]

2. Now add `UIScrollView` in the rest of part of the `ViewController` and give below constraints:

   - top to navgationBar `0px`
   - Leading, Trailing, bottom to superview as `0`.

Now your VC be like below. Red point indicating that you can constraint missing.  Don't worry about that until your components inside the `UIScrollView` not set properly it shows you same error.

[image]

3. Now add a `UIView` in your `UIScrollView` (says viewMain) and give constraints like this

   - top, bottom, leading, trailing to `scrollview` as `0`
   - Equal width to you `viewVC`. `viewVC` is the view of VC. you get this view when you take new `UIViewController`. Now your UI will be like

[image]

and your view hierarchy will be like

here I am assuming you just scrolling your view in vertical direction not in horizontal direction.

[image]

3. Now I am going to add 5 views of different height in `scrollview` check it out.
4. Add a view in `viewMain`(says viewYellow) and give constraint below;

   - top, leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`
   - height `180px`

[image]

Now your UI will be like

[image]

5. Now same as `step 4` add four more views (viewGreen, viewBlue, viewRed, viewPurple) and gives constraints like below

   - - `viewGreen :` 1. top to `viewYellow` `0px` 2. leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`and 3. height `150px`.
   - - `viewBlue :` 1. top to `viewGreen` `0px` 2. leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`and 3. height `80px`.
   - - `viewBlue :` 1. top to `viewGreen` `0px` 2. leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`and 3. height `80px`.
   - - `viewRed :` 1. top to `viewBlue` `0px` 2. leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`and 3. height `140px`.
   - - `viewPurple :` 1. top to `viewRed` `0px` 2. leading trailing to `mainView` as `0px`and 3. height `128px`. 4. bottom to `mainView` `0px`.

Now your UI and view hierarchy will be like below

[image]

[image]

Don't worry about `viewPurple` as it is little appear in the `UI` but available in hierarchy. it is `scrollView` and it is safe very much. See

[image]

**Note:** There is not constraints error and warning available in `UIViewController` because as I ready said you when you set internal component of `scrollView` properly with constraints constraints error will be solved.

**Important:**  **How ScrollView Height is Calculated**

As you set constraint of each view with top, bottom and height constraint to the `mainView` so `mainView` height is calculated as follow equation

```
mainView.height = viewYellow.top + viewYellow.height + .... for all view + viewPurple.bottom
```

and `scrollView` height will be calculated as follows:

```
scrollView.height = mainView.height
```

However every view have constant height so on rotation height will be same.

### Final Output

**portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, I have an _existing_ app which is handled a bit different than what you wrote above.  I was already aware of this.

Answer (score -1):

Select the *Book Details* `UIViewController` in your storyboard and then just select the root view. Delete it and then drag and drop a `UIScrollView` to your `UIViewController`. Your root view should now be a `UIScrollView`

**Note:** I personally prefer the following view hierarchy:

```
|---UIView
     |---UIScrollView
         |---UIView //(to act as a container)
              |---UIView
              |---UIView
              |---UIView
              |---UIView
```

Allows you to scale the application as required quite easily while also allowing autoLayout to quite easily manage setting the content size of your `UIScrollView`

Comment: NO, that doesn't work... the scrollview doesn't scroll; the orgin is 0,0, and the size is the same as the view.  and how do I create the "view hierarchy" you show above?