# How to set Dynamically UIScrollView height in Swift 4 IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, height, scrollview

If the height of scrollview not set. then scrollview will not scrollable.

To make it scrollable. I set height statically in code like this.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)
```

Is there any way i can set height dynamically??

Comment: best wat to use auto layout !!

Comment: can you explain it some more. Thanks

Comment: Using autolayout you need to give constraints to subviews of scrollview so from constraints scrollview content height is automatically calculated...you don't need to set it explicitly.

Comment: @MahendraGP It all depends on requirement.

Comment: It is not dependent on requirement no one is going to complain you that why you have used auto layouts or frames....its up to you what you want to go with....and auto layouts are now widely used than frames...

Comment: @MahendraGP I am not saying you'r wrong, even you are absolutly right but take a case when user adding subviews in scrollview by code work. There are many scenarios where doing UI from programatically is even more easier then by storyboard. Thatsy i said it depends on requirement.

Comment: I understood..but again its up to the developer that if he is good in auto layout then he can do all the this that can be done by frames.

Comment: You have to pass all subview `height` in `scrollView.contentSize.height`. if There's 3 labels in that than `lbl1.frame.size.height + lbl2.frame.size.height + lbl3.frame.size.height`

Comment: CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;    This will help you to find whole height of scrollview includes it subviews.

Answer (score 1):

One option using AutoLayout is to make *UIStackView* a subview of the *UIScrollView*. Set the constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom and width) of *UIStackView* to be equal to *UIScrollView*. Set the height of the subviews (alternatively make them dynamic to resize depending on their own subviews). Then add the subviews to the *UIStackView* by using addArrangedSubview and it will handle the constraints for you. The *UIScrollView's* contentSize will adapt to the *UIStackView* depending on it's subviews.

**Don't forget to change the axis property of *UIStackView* to vertical.**

Here is an example using *NSLayoutAnchor*:

```
override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let redView = UIView()
    redView.backgroundColor = .red
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0)
    ])

    let blueView = UIView()
    blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 700.0)
    ])

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .black
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(redView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
    ])

    self.view = view
}
```

If you don't want to use *UIStackView*, just add every subview directly to *UIScrollView* and set the constraints how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

- If you wanted to do with storyboard then first go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964016/unable-to-insert-uiscrollview-above-uiview-to-another-scene-using-xcode-8/42129746#42129746).
- If you wanted to do by code as you done it code then first you have to calculate the inner content height programatically the use the below code.

  ```
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: contentHeight)
  ```

Still have any query then ask.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to do it programmatically. So how to calculate the inner content height programmatically?

Comment: @SajidZeb As i said in comments it depends on your UI design. and code logic what you have done and how you done.